# FlatList Object and Value Showing Two Different Things

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a simple FlatList showing a list of object names. The FlatList calls the function nameCheck to see if the name of the object is null. When I log the whole object the name of the object shows null but when I log just the name it doesnt come up as null.

**console.log(item)**

> id: 1
>
> name: null
>
> team: "Blue"
>
> username: "user"

**console.log(item.name)**

> Bob

What is going on here?

```
render(){

 function nameCheck(item){
  console.log(item)
  console.log(item.name)
  if(item.name == null){
    return <Text>Name is Null</Text>
  }else{
    return <Text>Name is Not Null</Text>
  }
 }

 return (
  <FlatList
   data={this.state.objects}
   renderItem={({item}) => {
     {nameCheck(item)}
   }
   />
 )
```

Comment: could you show the `renderItem` implementation? Is it an asynchronous operation?

Comment: I dont believe the FlatList renderItem is a asyc.

Comment: not sure if this is related but it should be `renderItem={ ({item}) => nameCheck(item) }`, you have an extra expression block.

Comment: No change either way with or without block.

Answer (score 0):

properties of the object are case sensitive, it seems that the property Name is null and name is Bob, you wanna set the Name property of item to name

Answer (score 0):

Unless it’s a typo, it looks like `item` has a `Name` peppery (capitalized). You should double check that it’s `item.name`